# Linking sklearn LogisticRegression coefficients to terms in a sparse matrix, and getting statistical significance / C.I

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, coefficients

This is a continuation of a question that started in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667154/what-is-an-efficient-data-structure-for-tokenized-data-in-python/28667323?noredirect=1#comment45629601_28667323).

I have run a logistic regression using sklearn using code similar to that below:

```
from pandas import *
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import linear_model

vect= CountVectorizer(binary =True)

a = read_table('text.tsv', sep='\t', index_col=False)

X = vect.fit_transform(c['text'].values)

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1)

d = logreg.fit(X, c['label'])
d.coef_
```

Now I would like to link the values in d.coef_ to unique terms that constitute the rows in my sparse matrix X. What is the right way to do this? Can't seem to get this to work, even though it seems like X is supposed to have a vocabulary_ attribute. I get:

```
In [48]: X.vocabulary_
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-138ab7dd95ed> in <module>()
----> 1 X.vocabulary_

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
    497             return self.getnnz()
    498         else:
--> 499             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    500 
    501     def transpose(self):

AttributeError: vocabulary_ not found
```

And one step further, if I wanted to get statistical significance and confidence intervals on these coefficients (along the lines of what you get from R's glm), is that possible? e.g.,

```
## 
## Call:
## glm(formula = admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, family = "binomial", 
##     data = mydata)
## 
## Deviance Residuals: 
##    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
## -1.627  -0.866  -0.639   1.149   2.079  
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept) -3.98998    1.13995   -3.50  0.00047 ***
## gre          0.00226    0.00109    2.07  0.03847 *  
## gpa          0.80404    0.33182    2.42  0.01539 *  
## rank2       -0.67544    0.31649   -2.13  0.03283 *  
## rank3       -1.34020    0.34531   -3.88  0.00010 ***
## rank4       -1.55146    0.41783   -3.71  0.00020 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
## 
##     Null deviance: 499.98  on 399  degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance: 458.52  on 394  degrees of freedom
## AIC: 470.5
## 
## Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: Btw the columns in the matrix represent the terms, the rows are the documents.

Comment: There is no way to get the confidence intervals in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature names can be access from `vect` using the `get_feature_names` method.

You can zip them to the coefficients like this for example:

```
zip(vect.get_feature_names(),d.coef_[0])
```

This returns a tuple with `(token, coefficient)`

Comment: Thanks for your response - super helpful. I've expanded my question slightly, as I realized it didn't meet the scope of what I was curious about. If you have additional insight, that would be awesome!